# Using Apache Camel with Amazon AWS

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, apache-camel

Just wondering , I want to use Apache Camel with AWS ( SQS and SNS ). I have never used Camel before. I want to have distributed components that get messages from SQS and post responses to SNS. My understanding is that Apache Camel is pretty good at implementing such EIP architectures :-) So, does Camel automatically create all the SQS Queues, SNS Topics for me automatically or do I have to script those object creations using AWS Cloud Formation ?

Cheers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Camel is ideal for your scenario. You just need to visit the specific component documentation in order to know the details you are looking for:

1. [SQS Component](http://camel.apache.org/aws-sqs.html)
2. [SNS Component](http://camel.apache.org/aws-sns.html)

If you visit both, it says the the topics and queues will be created if they don't exist.