# Integrating Apache Camel to Amazon Kinesis Streaming Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-kinesis

Has anyone integrated Apache Camel to Amazon Kinesis Streaming Service?

This is related to [Using Apache Camel with Amazon AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577745/using-apache-camel-with-amazon-aws/21383065?noredirect=1#comment32249044_21383065) which includes a question about other Amazon services being integrated with Apache Camel.

I was hoping that Amazon Kinesis endpoints were in the process of being developed or exist in some early adoption form.

Thanks.

PS. Maybe someone with more 'reputation' points can add a amazon-kinesis tag to this post?  ;-)

Comment: Can you please describe better what you want to build? Reading or writing from Kinesis and probable not that complex.

Comment: Thanks, @aldrinleal!  @Guy - The Amazon Kinesis service provides an API for producing and consuming data on a stream.  It makes sense to provide camel connectors for both, in my opinion.  I agree that it should not be hard, but I was wondering if there was an effort underway, since other Amazon services are supported as camel endpoints.  Thanks!

Comment: Wanted to chime in that this would be useful for me, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinesis support will be part of Camel 2.17.0 release. 
2.17.0 is not yet released. It still in-progress.

Link to info: [Camel 2.17.0 release](http://camel.apache.org/camel-2170-release.html)